# How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL insert statement with where condition

Tags: php, sql

I got a problem below. I want to add some record to a row that already have id
This is just the example
    $name = "john";

```
MySQL_query("
    INSERT INTO customer(name) 
    VALUES ($name)
     WHERE customer_id=2344
");
```

Comment: I am afraid you are not clear. Usually records are synonym of rows. Do you want to `UPDATE` a row with `customer_id` `2344`?

Comment: You should consider using mysqli or PDO—`mysql_` functions are already officially deprecated. Using `$name` directly in your query without sanitizing presents a very real security risk.